# Powerpoint add-in, that improves navigation across large slide stacks?

Tags: powerpoint

Preparing a large presentation with dozens of backup slides, I have become frustrated with Powerpoint ability at navigating and outlining the content. The "sections" feature helps, but seems oddly limited.

- The "Normal" view gives me the choice between seeing too few slides at once (when making the navigation bar wide) and not being able to read the titles of either slides or sections.
- The "slide sorter" view provides the best overview, but would be much more useful, if it were possible to [use it as navigation bar replacement](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/37425091-make-side-bar-of-normal-view-work-like-slide-so) in "Normal" view. See e.g. [this mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BoNX.jpg).
- The "Outline" view could provide the best overview, but oddly doesn't display the foldable sections created in other views. It can also have an extensive startup time, when the slides contain equations.
- The "Section" feature itself is limited, as it doesn't allow nesting: It would be vastly helpful, to be able to group sections, e.g. in order to be able to fold away all backup slides at once while still structuring the backup slides by topic.

I was wondering if there are any add-ins available, that help with these aspects. The most useful would probably addin's for

- nestable sections, and
- section-support in outline view.

Sadly, with powerpoint, a google search for add-ins is flooded with "the complete list of best powerpoint addins" articles, that just keep repeating the same addins for simple editing tasks, so I wasn't successful in judging if such an addin exists.

---

I am running Office 2019 (via Office 365 Personal). At work I am using Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it fits exactly what you want, but I'm thinking of 1 add-in that I find helpful for managing large decks, called Power-user. 
There is an Agenda builder that allows to navigate easily within the presentation. 
How it works:
- You get a pane on the right that lists all the slides
- The titles are visible and you can click on any title to navigate to that specific slide.
- You can see the sections, collapse or expand them
- You can also create sub-sections
- You can generate and update agenda pages automatically based on the sections you create

This is how it looks:
[image]

Link: https://www.powerusersoftwares.com

Comment: Sadly, the software is also 3x as expensive as the office license at 200€/year, so it's not viable to get it when needing only the one feature... Note that the Agenda builder is explicitly *not* part of the "free" version. They do have a free academic license option though. Sadly, no personal option.